# Multi-booting a secure-boot enabled Windows 8 laptop

Tags: windows-8, multi-boot, ubuntu-12.10, secure-boot

My friend is buying a Lenovo Z500 with Windows 8 pre-installed and with that (irritating) Secure Boot feature. We use Ubuntu for some stuff at college and she wants me to help her install Ubuntu 12.10 on the system. I am not sure how to do on Secure Boot machines and I would like some help/resources on this. Another friend of mine who bought a Dell Inspiron with Secure Boot faced a lot of problems in dual booting **even after turning off** Secure Boot.

Hence, I would like some foolproof advice on this matter. Thanks.

Comment: You will need to look at the manual for his device to discover the steps to disable Secure Boot.  until you have the physical device in your hands, we can't really help, since your suppose to have an actual problem to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Secureboot MSFT has really made things very difficult for people who want to do dual boot, as it requires OS to be certified by MSFT, which is generally not the case of Linux distros. But there are plenty of posts available for different methods and as usual it is not guaranteed to work 100% on all machines.

But I have Lenovo Y500 and I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 on it using [these instructions from Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system) (SU sister site) with some modifications and it has worked for me. But please remember to not to mess up OKR partition or there will be no way to go back in event of installation went sideways

Comment: I don't understand down vote. Did you actually looked at the link I mentioned ? It does mention that you need to disable secure boot from bios.